# Finding number of surjections from a set $A$ with $n$ elements to a set $B$ with $2$ elements

Tags: functions, permutations, combinations

[image]

I don’t understand why subtracting $2$.

Comment: I mean, it tells you in the solution why. There are two functions that aren't surjective

Comment: What are those 2 function which arent surjective?

Comment: Please fill in the missing words that your image doesn't capture.

Comment: Let $B = \{\alpha, \beta\}$. The two non-surjective functions $f_1, f_2: A\to B$ must be $f_1$ which maps every element of A to $\alpha \in B$, and $f_2$ which maps every element of $A$ to $\beta \in B$.  Hence out of $2^n$ total functions from $A \to B$, we subtract the number of functions which are not surjective, which means, $2^n - 2$ surjective functions from A to B.

Answer (score 1):

Every non-surjective function either maps everyone to $x$ or everyone to $y$. There's only one function of each kind.